# Create custom ProvisioningHandler in WSO2 IS

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am creating a custom provisioning handler and try to deploy the jar in /repository/components/lib and I modify  in application-authentication.xml. 
When I run the server, I encountered this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/wso2/carbon/identity/application/authentication/framework/internal/FrameworkServiceComponent
at com.mycompany.wso2.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.provisioning.impl.CustomProvisioningHandler.handle(CustomProvisioningHandler.java:75)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.sequence.impl.DefaultStepBasedSequenceHandler.handleJitProvisioning(DefaultStepBasedSequenceHandler.java:714)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.sequence.impl.DefaultStepBasedSequenceHandler.handlePostAuthentication(DefaultStepBasedSequenceHandler.java:424)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.sequence.impl.DefaultStepBasedSequenceHandler.handle(DefaultStepBasedSequenceHandler.java:156)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultAuthenticationRequestHandler.handle(DefaultAuthenticationRequestHandler.java:115)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator.handle(DefaultRequestCoordinator.java:135)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.CommonAuthenticationHandler.doPost(CommonAuthenticationHandler.java:46)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.CommonAuthenticationHandler.doGet(CommonAuthenticationHandler.java:37)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.sendRequestToFramework(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:1013)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.sendToFrameworkForAuthentication(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:457)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.handleSPInitSSO(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:360)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.handleRequest(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:195)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.doPost(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:107)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:60)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
...
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.internal.FrameworkServiceComponent cannot be found by custom_wso2_1.0_1.0.0
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 58 more
```

Comment: What's your Identity Server version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seem to have a dependency to

```
org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.internal.FrameworkServiceComponent
```

But this is wrong, you can't refer to a class in a internal package of another component. That is a private package. It is the reason for this error.

Comment: I'm having the same problem above, I would like to ask how to proceed to retrieve the services (in particular "RealmService" and "RegistryService"), normally retrievable using the "FrameworkServiceComponent", that are needed when extending the "DefaultProvisioningHandler" (due to the fact that these services are needed in the "handle" method). Thanks in advance